# How to integrate programs written in different programming languages?

Tags: java, python, integration

I have two developers in my team. One will develop a Python application, the other will develop a Java application. The Java app generates a boolean value which is used by the Python app.

How can I integrate these applications? I have thought about using:

- Return codes: Python app calls the Java app, then the Java app uses
  the return code to inform the boolean value.
- Sockets: Connect both
  applications through sockets and exchange information. I think this
  is overkill.
- Files: The Java app does its stuff, writes the output to
  a file, then the Python app reads this file and retrieves the boolean
  value it needs.

Any other suggestions? I'm not just looking for a solution, I'm also considering here aspects such as code organization and "beauty" of the overall solution.

---

Edit 1:
Thank you @user2387370 for the recommendation of using Jython, but I can't use it.

---

Edit 2: Thank you @RickyA, I'll have a look at messaging systems (such as zeromq, which you mentioned).

Comment: For intermingling Java and Python, try Jython

Comment: Why are you using two different languages? What happens if one programmer is away when something goes wrong?

Comment: Why not Jython as a choice not to use it implies constraints that you have not given in the question

Comment: @Mark Because I have to, unfortunately I can't avoid this situation.

Comment: So what else can't you do?

Comment: Basically I've got two developers with very specific skillsets and I can't tell them to develop in another language, even if it is just an integration layer. They have to concentrate in the real problem, and the integration should be done in a way that both of them can develop in their own programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a messaging system like [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/). That has libraries for both languages and allows you to integrate them seamlessly.

Your proposed options will get clunky interoperability. (filelocks, dead sockets, dead processes etc..)

Also [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ScriptingJava) page lists some tools that can be used for pyton/java interop. I can't recommend one since I used none.

Comment: That is a good idea, we have worked with RabbitMQ in another project (OpenStack). I'll have a look at zeromq. Thanks for the suggestion and sorry that I can't vote it up.

Comment: Welcome btw., your first question is a good one, despite what others might think.